# "in control of their own destiny": a contradiction?

Tags: meaning, contradiction

It's almost NFL playoff time, which means every two-bit sports reporter and analyst [sic] is talking about teams "in control of their own destiny," by which they normally mean: if they play well, they can get into the postseason.

This is now a maddening (no pun intended) cliche, and I know I'm not alone in wondering: is this not a contradiction? I seem to remember even Steve Young complaining about this a couple of years back right around this time.

> destiny (n): the events that will necessarily happen to a particular person or thing in the future

The above definition is from Google dictionary, but I was dismayed to see it followed by this example:

> "she was unable to control her own destiny"

Of course she was! Because it was her *destiny*!

But wait... ESPN did not, apparently, initiate this apparent contradiction. Perhaps they've been taking cues from Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar*, in which Cassius says:

> Men at some time are masters of their fates:
>
> The fault, dear Brutus, is not in our stars,
>
> But in ourselves, that we are underlings. (1.2.9)

However, you may say, Cassius's entire point is that fate is a foolish notion, that free will reigns.

Still, I return to my initial question, and although it does seem that an all-powerful hand is guiding the NFL (how else to get such parity, compared to the other major sports?), I believe the teams do have control.... just not of their "destiny."

So: contradiction in terms or no? Can NFL teams, or mere individuals, "control" their own "destiny?"

Comment: The principle sense defined by [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/destiny) is the fate-divorced: 
**destiny** noun       
C1 [C] the things that will happen in the future.  'In control of one's own destiny' is of course a contradiction in terms rather than a paradox if the fate-associated sense is demanded.

Comment: There's no such thing as destiny. Apart from the word and the responsibility shirking concept, that is.

Comment: They don't mean their _destiny_ -- as @JoeDark points out, there isn't any such thing -- they just mean control of their future actions.

Comment: Football commentary is by definition nonsensical.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense @HotLicks

Comment: @Rusty Tuba, Hot Licks was compelled.

Comment: Football commentary is theatre.  Trying to make sense of it is like trying to make sense of Jabberwocky.

Comment: Interesting... I've seen jabberwocky analyzed here. Is this a case of "provide your context so that we may judge it?" You are free to ignore this question if it doesn't jibe with your interests.

Comment: That's a philosophical question -I thought philosophical questions are not accepted on this site. How come this one is accepted and  upvoted too. This site never ceases to surprise me!

Comment: I feel like this question was one sided and you've asked it only to deal in answers that add a plinth to your own idea of what it means.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning here is quite specific. A team **controls its own destiny** if it reaches the playoffs by winning all its remaining games *regardless of the outcome of other games*.

So, for example: Suppose there is one game remaining, Teams A and B are tied in the standings with one to qualify for the playoffs, and Team A has a tie-breaking advantage over Team B for some reason. In the last regular game, A plays C and B plays D. A controls its destiny: it qualifies with a win over C. B does not. It needs not only to win, but moreover for A to lose. (Modify as necessary for games where draws occur.)

Comment: This is exactly right. As the term is understood idiomatically, a team that "controls its own destiny" doesn't have to rely on help from other teams in order to reach the playoffs. Simply by winning all (or some smaller number) of its remaining games, it can ensure that it will qualify for the playoffs.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the intricacies of the English language, the phrase is commonly bent to represent someone influencing outcomes based on changeable variables (a good example is Andrew Lazarus's Answer), but the fact remains that, **at it's core definition, it IS a contradiction** because destinies do not have changeable variables. They are predetermined and absolute.

## Define the keywords:

"*Destiny*" is defined as "*the events that will necessarily happen to a particular person or thing in the future.*"

"*Control*" is defined as "*the power to influence or direct people's behavior or the course of events.*"

## Now put the two together in a logical equation:

`"events that will necessarily happen" == "power to influence course of events"`

**You cannot influence events that will necessarily happen. They happen necessarily, with or without your help/interference.**

That makes the above logic false, which indicates a contradiction.